# nginx compile with modules

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I compile nginx from source with this option:

```
--add-module=/tmp/headers-more-nginx-module-0.33
```

after compiling I delete the directory **/tmp/headers-more-nginx-module-0.33** but the module is still usable. 
So, I guess, this module is compiled in nginx and included, right?
But why I see in the nginx -V output still the tmp directory for this module?

```
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --add-module=/tmp/headers-more-nginx-module-0.33
```

Answer (score 1):

The `configure arguments:` part of `nginx -V` output will contain whatever configuration arguments were passed to `./configure` script *before compilation*.

So it's OK to observe whatever old/non-existent paths you had there for `--add-module`. They are not in use during run time. They only specify path of a module's `config` file during compilation.

The output is "remembered" for `nginx -V`, so that you have a record of how NGINX was compiled.